# Universal character name inside literal?

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding, literals

In `u '\uXXXX'` is the UCN first converting to the corresponding codepoint (ISO/IEC 10646) and then converting to the corresponding prefix? In this case u (UTF-16)?

Or what is the encoding of a UCN inside such a literal, if there is a prefix which explicitly defines the encoding?

Comment: [character_literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) has such examples.

Comment: @Jarod42 oh wait, doesn't have UTF-16 and the codepoints of UCNs have the same codepoints / encoding? Whoops?

Comment: @Jarod42 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape also has information about `\u` and `\U`